# java method using generics to convert Enumeration to HashMap

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, enumeration, using

I'm trying to abstract a method that loads a static hashmap with Integer, String values from an enumeration.   My specific method looks something like this

```
public static Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>;
static{
    Enumeration<MyEnum> enumTokens = MyEnum.getTokens(); //returns an enumeration of 'MyEnum'
    //like to abstract  the following into a method
    while (enumTokens.hasMoreElements()){
        MyEnum element = (MyEnum) enumTokens.nextElement();
        myMap.put(element.intValue(), element.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is? This is not even a method...

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to mix static block with abstract method.

Comment: Show the source for `MyEnum`, and enough context for us to be able to understand what you're asking.

Comment: What's your problem? Where are you facing exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic method that will do it for you.

Note that you haven't said what the significance of `intValue()` is, so I've created an interface for it.

```
interface HasIntValue {
    int intValue();
}

public static <E extends Enumeration<E> & HasIntValue> Map<Integer, String> convertToMap(E e) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()){
        E element = e.nextElement();
        map.put(element.intValue(), element.toString());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Note the syntax that allows a type bound to *both* `Enumeration` *and* `HasIntValue`

Comment: Why is `E` self-referencing? Are you confusing `Enumeration` with `Enum`? What you have is akin to declaring `<I extends Iterable<I> & HasIntValue>`.